# How to access data of query Comment.group('user').count

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The query below in Rails console:

```
i = Comment.group('user_id').count
```

gives me output like this:

```
{1=>3, 2=>6, 3=>2, 4=>8}
```

where `1,2,3,4` are user ids and `3,6,2,8` are the count of the rows with these user ids. Please shed some light on me on how I can use these data. As `i.count` gives me total no.
I want to access these individual user row counts. Again, `i[0].count` or `i[1].count` gives me an error.

Comment: I have edited my question now.
I want to access these individual row counts 3, 6, 2, 8 in my calculations. But don't know the way to use this output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression gives you a Ruby [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html) of key/value pairs, which you can access using the following:

```
i[1] # => 3
i[2] # => 6
... etc ...
```

You don't need to call `count` on them, the value of calling `i[2]` will be the count.

Comment: Note also that, if you plan to use this within a Rails view, you'll need to use an instance variable (like `@counts`) instead of a local variable (like `i`) in order for it to be visible within the view

Comment: Yes, thanks for this extra information. :)
I had just put that `i` for example here.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you can access the hash with `i[1]` to get the comment count for the user with ID #1, instead of adding `.count` as you did in your example.